# Transparency in Illustrator: text with outline

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

In the following logo created by a designer, the Forever de Sales text is two layers: text + outline. I am trying to make the white portion of the text transparent. Whatever methods I try, it either doesn't work at all or some portion of the shape of the outline shows thru making it look odd. I need the exact steps to make this work. Making the M transparent was easy; the text, not so much. Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACp95.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this **on a copy** of the file to see if it gets you what you want, it should....

- Select everything
- Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` if it's available in the menu
- Make certain everything is still selected
- Choose `Object > Expand` from the menu
- On the **Pathfinder Panel** (Window > Pathfinder) click the `Merge` button.
- Use the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow) to click the white areas you want to remove and hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

Of course, seeing how the shapes are actually constructed via the Layers and Appearance Panel would help answer. But this should be a workable general solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but if they are literally on two separate layers, you might want to start with combining them on the same layer. IF you meant that they are just layered on top of each other, you have to make sure that the bottom layers which is the "outlined" version is literally outlined. IF it is an outline that contains a stroke the it won't work. You have outline the Stroke by going to the top menu under Object > Path > Outline stroke. Once you do that you might have to go in a clean it by taking out an inner path that usually remains. Then select the white and gold/yellow and applying Pathfinder-Minus front. You should be good at that point. Hope this helps.